# How to set default smallIcon and largeIcon in an Android notification received?

Tags: android, notifications, icons, pushbots

I'm actually using [PushBots](https://pushbots.com/) to implement [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) notifications for my application.

They give me the option, when I create the notification, to use a specific field where I can set the `largeIcon` for my push. If I use that, I get something like this:

[image]

But, if I dont use that, I get this:

[image]

I would like to know if is it possible to set a default `smallIcon` and `largeIcon` for every notification (push) that my app recieve or change that white box that appears for my own app icon.

**1- Note: I don't create the notification in my code, I create it in the PushBots website Drashboard.**

**2- Note: `largeIcon` and `smallIcon`**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after hours looking the source code of PushBots, I just found out a solution.

In Android Studio, go to `File -> New -> Image Asset`. Then, choose `Notification Icon`. Now customize your new small Icon and, before finish it, put the name `white_notification_icon` for this new asset.

Android Studio will say to you that the file already exists and it is going to be overwritten. Say yes.

Now, you have a smallIcon by default already set!

Answer (score 0):

> Please refer following code

```
   NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.small_notification);
    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBitmapFromURL("YOURURL"));

    if (version >= 23) {
        mBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
    } else {
        mBuilder.setColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    }
```

> As per guide line small icon is compulsory and should be in white color or in gray color with alpha back ground  [refer this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35450412/2017307)

Comment: yes it works in my  case just put your icon path correctly

Comment: Where I must put this code? In my MainActivity.java?

Comment: in my case i have a broadcast receiver i have kept this code in receiver so when ever that receiver receive event it call this code

Comment: go to link specified in this answer and get the entire function for notification

Comment: Your answer will solve the problem if I would create the notifications from the code, but i dont do that. There is the problem, I just want to set a smallIcon and a largeIcon for every notification that I recieve, not that I create.

Comment: do you want it it only for your application or for all application on device